# IsolatedStorageFile - Windows Phone 8: Can not read file again after shutdown Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstoragefile

I tried to test following this code: 
[BackgroundFileTransfer](https://github.com/jeffblankenburg/31DaysOfMango/blob/master/Day26-BackgroundFileTransfer.zip)

After download file, if you play it immediately, the media plays well. But if you shutdown the Emulator, and run it again, there is no media file in Storage.
I don't know how to save this file to see it again in next run application. Help me!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows phone emulator is a `virtual device` for testing apps in Devlopement. Every time when you ShutDown,its `instance is destroyed with application and its isolatedStorage` too and after it Starting it again it takes up new instance and again `new IsolatedStorage Space for application` when its again installed. so you can not manage data if you are shuttig down it While in windows phone Device it stores application in Device Memory so it doesnt get Destroyed untill you reset your phone or Unistall tha Applcation.

You can use Device for testing and managing Application's `IsolatedStorage`.

Comment: Thank so much, I haven't tried it on Device. But now I think it's a good way to resolve this problem. Thank again!!!